# load script through a custom function

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'd like to load scripts through a script that I called `loader.sh`.

```
#### Loader.sh
uload() {
    # ...
    if ! is_loaded $file
    then
        . "${file}" || exit 3

        if [[ ! -z "${callback}" ]]
        then
            "${callback}"
        fi
    fi
}

### log.sh
declare -r WARN=3

warn() {
    echo "${WARN}: $@" >&2
}
```

### Use case:

```
. "${loader.sh}"

uload "log.sh"

warn 'test'
```

This causes this error:

```
WARN: unbound variable
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is symptomatic for these two together:

- the `-u` option being set, which causes unset variables to trigger the error of `unbound variable`
- the `WARN` variable has not been set

To confirm or exclude this situation, do:

- check with `echo $-` if the `u` flag is set
- try if you can to manually `echo "$WARN"` to make sure it's set or debug using the `x` option

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

When replace `declare -r` with `readonly` I don't get the error anymore.

> Using the declare builtin restricts the scope of a variable.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html

So this is how I fixed it:

```
### log.sh
readonly WARN=3

warn() {
    echo "${WARN}: $@" >&2
}
```

Comment: Well done. Only in your question, and in this answer as well, the declaration is in the general scope, so this shouldn't matter.

Comment: It is not actually, because I specified `### filename` above every script, so it's not in the general scope. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Still, the scope is general. Comments don't constitute scopes. Or was this your convention? (For what?)

Comment: @tomasz what I meant is they are files, every `### filename` means that the script is in a file named `filename`. Sorry I'm not sure I understood you right

Comment: Even though they're in the general scope if the file is sourced. `declare` should be fine.